# Lua - Capture the redirect URL and provided parameter information

Tags: http, lua

I’m trying out the Fitbit api, to learn about about OAuth 2.0, and the authorisation code i need in the process is something fitbit provide, appended to a domain name I provide..  (More specific details are here - https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/developer-guide/authorization/ )

Here’s an example of a redirect URL that’s you’re taken too to get an authorisation code.

```
https://myapp.com/callback?code=d62d6f5bdc13df79d9a5f#_=_
```

And it’s the `d62d6f5bdc13df79d9a5f` part of that new page/URL which I need..

Is it possible with Lua to capture the redirected URL that fitbit issue?

Please consider me a mere novice/intermediate with Lua, so go easy on me. :-). Thanks is advance…

Comment: Your question is unfortunately very unclear. If you want to redirect that part, why not go with `local code = url:match"^https://myapp%.com/callback%?code=(.-)#"`?

Comment: Hi @LMD, many thanks for responding, I would appreciate any help on how to explain this better, as i tried my best, plus I included a link to the Fitbit OAuth process to add extra context..  The redirect to a registered domain i provide them with,  is done by Fitbit themselves.. its the code they append to that domain i need to extract..  - if it helps I’ve tried to reword my original post/question

Comment: The line of code in my comment will extract the code and store it in a local variable `code`.

Comment: Hi @LMD, thanks, my key question is how do i capture the redirected URL Fitbit provide? I have to make a request to one URL first, and the result (with the required code) is provided within the provided redirect URL?  Can I capture a redirect URL using Lua ?